# PHP cURL proxy new window

Tags: javascript, php, curl, proxy, window.open

I would like to know if this is possible. I have some code like this

```
$ch = curl_init();  // Initialise a cURL handle
$proxy = "10.20.30.40:1234";
$url = "stackoverflow.com";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$results = curl_exec($ch);  // Execute a cURL request
curl_close($ch);    // Closing the cURL handle
```

This works great and will load the specified page through the proxy. However, what I want is to target "_blank" as if a user clicked a link to open it in a new window.

And, I need to take it one step further.

I know it's possible to open a new window via javascript and have it closed after a specified period of time (say 10 minutes). Using something like this:

```
<script>
var url = 'stackoverflow.com';
var t = 1000 * 60 * 10;
var win = window.open(url,    '_blank','width=1400,height=800,left=1,top=1');
setTimeout(function () { win.close();}, t);
</script>
```

But the problem with that is that it will not open via a proxy.

So, my question is:  Can I somehow combine this code, either through Ajax, or javascript or do it entirely in PHP (preferable) or if necessary to do it entirely in JS?

I would ultimately like to be able to open a new window to a specified URL through a specified proxy. Then close the window after a specified timeout.

As a matter of fact, I would like to avoid Ajax if possible because of the CORS errors it causes.

**NOTE: I do not know jquery, would like this to work in PHP/JS. However if jquery is the only way to do it and you can provide the complete code to use jquery, I would consider it.**

Any help would be most appreciated.